# file_put_contents in the folder below

Tags: php, file, directory

I'm making a file creating script in php using file_put_contents, so how do you place a file to the directory below?
For example the script is in localhost:8080/favicon/ and I want to place the file in localhost:8080, how can this be done?

Comment: If you are using xampp/apache they have the `htdocs` folder. If you use wamp, you have the `www` folder.

Answer (score 1):

```
$dest = __DIR__ . '/../filename';
file_put_contents($dest, $data);
```

See http://php.net/manual/language.constants.predefined.php

Answer (score 0):

fclose(fopen(path_to_your_file_like_C:\abc,"a"));
for more info go [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).